# What would be the easiest way to convert a SQL Server record into a JSON insert for MongoDB?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mongodb

I have a SQL Server table that I need to convert into a Mongo document. However the table has about 50 fields that I do not want to input one by one. Anyone know of a simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this in code, e.g. C#? Please expand this question and let us know. When you've done that flag to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your data from SQL Server in JSON/CSV/TSV format and later import it in MongoDB using mongoimport tool.

You can find information about importing data in MongoDB on this link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools